# How to melt multiple column pairs each pair containing values for male and female genders separately for each year in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe with columns like `"id"`, `"company name"`, `"company type"` but also columns like `"Year 1 Males Total"`, `"Year 1 Females Total"`, `"Year 2 Males Total"`, `"Year 2 Females Total"` etc. How to convert this wide format to deep format obtaining previous columns  `"id"`, `"company name"`, `"company type"` and `"Year 1"`, `"Year 2"` but additional `"Gender"` column where each previous sample is going to be separated into two rows, one for male and one for female?

I tried this which resulted in melting years correctly but for each new row, all of the other columns were NaN

```
df_copy = df.copy()
for i in range(1,12):
    df_copy = pd.concat([df_copy, df.melt(value_vars=[f'Year {i} Males Total', f'Year {i} Females Total'], var_name='Gender', value_name=f'Year {i}')], axis=1)
    df_copy.drop(columns=[f'Year {i} Males Total',f'Year {i} Females Total', f'Year {i} Total'],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Comment: Kindly share sample data with expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
#create MultiIndex in index
df1 = df.set_index(['id','company name','company type'])
#create MultiIndex in columns extract years and Males or Females substrings
df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df1.columns.str.extract(r'(\d+)\s+(Males|Females)'))
#reshape for years in columns
df1 = df1.rename_axis([None, 'Gender'], axis=1).stack().add_prefix('Year ').reset_index()
```